# How to host a PHP application in Openshift?

Tags: php, git, openshift

I'm new to Openshift. I do not know anything about Git and Openshift. Please guide me to host my PHP application in Openshift.

I have created my domain name in Openshift and added MySQL and phpMyAdmin. And also tell me about database storages in Openshift. I'm using the free plan.

Comment: This is rather too broad here - a whole book could be written on this. If you can, please edit the question to describe a problem you are actually having with Openshift?

Answer (score 1):

I would start by reading through this overview: https://www.openshift.com/developers/php.
You will need to use the command line a little bit to create your application. You should be able to just do:

```
$ rhc app create MyApp php-5.4
$ rhc cartridge add mysql-5.5 -a MyApp
```

If you're more specific about what you're hosting I can provide more details. The page I referenced above has tons of tutorials and videos you can watch.

Storage engines listed are:
 - MySQL
 - MongoDB
 - PostgreSQL

It sounds like you want to use MySQL. I don't know what applications you're hosting, but MySQL is a good choice for apps like Wordpress.